# How to prevent voltage spike from BLDC motor in ESC circuit

Tags: stm32, power-electronics, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, voltage

I'm implementing the circuit below by modifying it using STM32 (Bluepill) and adding some decoupling capacitors (100nF) to the bluepill and LM339 with the supply from the battery also connected to the decoupling capacitor (470uF). For bluepill power supply source, I use Stepdown Mini 360 (buck converter module with ic mp2307).

When I start the bldc motor, the motor spins intermittently and the green LED (PC13) on the bluepill turns off and on. I checked the 3.3V voltage on the bluepill as well as the LM339 and found that there was a voltage spike. If the motor does not move or the commutation of the coil does not change. The 3.3v voltage on the bluepill looks stable. When the motor is running, the voltage to 3.3v on the bluepill has voltage spikes.

How to remove the voltage spike and Bluepill works stably?

I'm planning to increase the decoupling capacitor to 22uF. Can this help reduce spikes in the bluepill supply voltage?

[image]

[image]

-edited-

Comment: How is the 5V or 3.3V supplied to the circuit?  Click the edit link below your question and add this please.  If 5V comes from the 12V supply (like through an LM7805 regulator or something), then spikes there (on the 12V side) are likely making their way through that regulator.  But nobody can answer this definitively until this is cleared up.

Comment: I use Stepdown Mini 360 (buck converter module with ic mp2307).

Comment: Try tossing a diode in series with the supply to the Bluepill. Maybe the stall current is bogging down the voltage and causing the Blue Pill to brownout.